# Trying unsuccesfully to create a convolution layer to 2 dim input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, mfcc

I'm doing my final project on the first degree studies. In short i'm taking 772 training sound files that each sound file have 327  sound features coeffs called mfcc, so my x_training input is - 772*327.

I asked recomended to me what model to use and I was answeared -

> Try CNN on MFCC (add 4 or so CNN layers followed by Max Pooling) -> Flatten -> Dense Layers This is a very generic architecture that works for most tasks of this nature – Iordanis 2 days ago

So I tried to create it using tensorflow -

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:])),
     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
     tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')
])
```

( the integers values are completly random )

when x_train.shape[1:] is 327 ( number of mfcc coeffs in each sound file )

but unfortuentlly it didn't work for me and it writes -

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None,
312]
```

I tried to down the convulution layer to 1D but it also didn't work ( just changed the error to excepted 3d instead 4d )

Someone know  what should I do...

Sorry for my english and sorry if it stupid question, I'm pretty new to tensorflow :)

Edit :

I did the following things but now it's write me that:

TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple' 
on the dense layer

> ```
> x_train.reshape((-1, 1))
> x_test.reshape((-1, 1))
> model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
>      tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:], 1)),
>      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2),
>      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
>      tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
> ```

I also did it :

> ```
> x_train.reshape((-1, 1))
> x_test.reshape((-1, 1))
> model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
>      tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:])),
>      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2),
>      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
>      tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
> ```

but got the error before -

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer:
>   expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 312]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your training data has only one feature-dimension, use `Conv1D` instead of `Conv2D`. Then your input has a 3d shape like `(?, x, 1)`, where the first dimension will be the batch-size, the second one are the features, and the last one contains the values itself.
So try to reshape your data first via

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(np.append(x_train.shape, 1))
```

and `input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:])` should work fine.

Please note that you also have to change your pooling to `MaxPooling1D` afterwards!

Comment: If you first reshape your data you have to use `input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:])`, not `input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:], 1)`. Sorry if I confused you with that.

Comment: i tried also that but it write me the same error before

Comment: ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None,

Comment: this what i did now :


    x_train.reshape((-1, 1))
    x_test.reshape((-1, 1))
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
         tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:])),
         tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2),
         tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake I think. Please see the edit of my post!

Comment: Ok I will try it soon I had to go :(